# What is the meaning of "Mc" in some words initiating with that?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

As you all know some words start with the "**Mc**", namely **McDonald's**, **McMaster**, **Mccorbin**, etc.
Now, I want to know what the meaning of "Mc" is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Son of"  It's Scottish and found in names.  The English equivalents would be Donaldson, Masterson, and Corbinson.

Like the English names, the patronymic has turned into a surname.

Comment: One of the news heads in an Indian daily today was felt interesting to many.  A small hut-like shop in North India is named "Gupta & Daughters" against the general convention of using ...sons... in place of daughters.  It was pleasing to see, and was hailed by many as it set an example.

Comment: Is there any source to back this up?